# Which Rabbi Chanina is stam Rabbi Chanina?

Tags: names, talmud-gemara, tannaim

In the Talmud when it says, "Rabbi Chanina says ...", which Rabbi Chanina is it referring to, Rabbi Chanina Ben Dosa, Rabbi Chanina ben Hama, etc..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this page on Dafi-Yomi.com](http://daf-yomi.com/DYItemDetails.aspx?itemId=24773), it's Rabbi Chanina ben Hama, a student of Rebbi Yehuda haNasi.

> רבי חנינא "סתם" הוא רבי **חנינא בר חמא** ,
>   היה תלמידו של רבי יהודה הנשיא‏

Other sources:

- [Ohr Yisroel](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_50520_212.pdf)
- [Virtual BM](http://www.bmv.org.il/Shiurim/avot/avot-h159.html)